# Reversing list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, reverse

I am starting with prolog, and as an exercise I am trying to reverse a list.

For example, `inv([1,2,3], S)` should give `S = [3,2,1].`
Below is what a partner and I have already done:

```
conc([], L, L).
conc([X|L1], L2, [X|L3]) :- conc(L1, L2, L3).

tail([X|Y], S) :- conc([], Y, S).

inv([X|Y], S) :- tail([X|Y], TAIL), inv(TAIL, R_TAIL), conc(R_TAIL, X, S).
inv([], []).
```

The first three lines work fine.  But  really don't understand what's going on with the last two, and therefore how to fix it.
I just wanna **find the tail** (this is working, when I just use the `tail` function) of the list, reverse it and then append it to the head of the list.
Could you help me guys?

Comment: Your problem is that you try to solve everything with your conc/3 predicate (which is usually called append/3). Think about your tail/2 predicate. What is it doing? It removes the first element from a list and concatenates the empty list to the tail of the list in order to get the tail of the list. That is superfluous. the variable Y contains already the tail of the list. Thus, if you really need a tail predicate than the simple fact `tail([_X|Y],Y).` does the job.

Comment: Your code is not working, because in the second last line you write `conc(R_TAIL,X,S)` where R_TAIL is a list and X is a list element. Thus you try to concatenate an element with a list (with `conc(R_TAIL,[X],S)` it would work). Try to always look at the trace of a simple query (e.g. `inv([1,2],X)`), in order to understand what happens.

Comment: @JoanC Yeah, it worked :).
Thanks for the answer. I'm really beginning with prolog and this syntax problems well.. I think it is supposed to happen to me :p

Comment: @JoanC thanks for the tip about how to get the tail. Be able to change the way I receive some argument is something I am definitely not used to.
And 'conc' it comes from "concatenar" (I'm from Brasil).

Answer (score 2):

Alternative foldl/4 based solution:

```
prepend_element(E, L, [E|L]).

inv(List, Reversed) :-
    foldl(prepend_element, List, [], Reversed).
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work for me.

Try this way instead:

```
?- reverse([1,2,3],Xs), write(Xs).

reverse(Xs,Ys) :- reverse(Xs,[],Ys).

reverse([],A,A).
reverse([H|T],R,A) :- reverse(T,[H|R],A).
```

Comment: Why use `write/1` on the [tag:prolog-toplevel]?

Comment: @repeat - It's just to display the value of `Xs` to the console. It's not needed for the computation.

Comment: I don't quite get that. The toplevel shows the variable bindings anyway so why use `write/1`?

Comment: @repeat - the prolog I use doesn't. I have to write out the results.